# Error 415 while sending an XML to REST WS

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest

I am trying to mock a WS. I have created following method in WS

```
@POST
@Consumes (MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void dataIn (InputStream inXml){
    System.out.println ("data received");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inXml));
    String xml = null;
    try {
        while ((xml = br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(xml);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println ("ouch");
    }

}
```

and i am sending an XML using my Java client by this code

```
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><rootElem name=\"xml_type\"><info>this_is_test</info></rootElem>";
    service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(xml);
```

But i am getting this exception

`Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://localhost:8080/project/ws/services/1.0/savedata returned a response status of 415`

I am pretty sure that I am not sending my XML properly. After doing couple of Googling, I couldn't figure out what is wrong i am doing. Since most of the tutorials/help i am finding online is using OBJ > JAXB > XML > JAXB > OBJ translation from client to server. I want to send raw xml and to read raw xml. Can someone suggest me what is wrong i am doing here?

---

I am not sure if answering own questions would result in -ve reputation or not. but after stumbling upon and figuring out things, I used Apache httpclient to send the request and it worked fine. I would request to close the question.

```
DefaultHttpClient dhc = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/project/ws/services/1.0/savedata");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><rootElem name=\"xml_type\"><info>this_is_test</info></rootElem>");
se.setContentType("application/xml");
postRequest.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response = dhc.execute(postRequest);
System.out.println (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```